# How to change the focus of QLineEdit automatically to another QLineEdit after input satisfy a criterion?

Tags: qt, focus, qlineedit

I have two `QLineEdit` widgets, `edt1` and `edt2`. Each QLineEdit can only accept two digits. After I input xx (e.g. 10) in `edt1`, which can satisfy the input criterion, how to change the focus from `edt1` to `edt2` automatically.

Is there built in function to use to make this happen? Or, can anyone provide something about how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if [`edt1.hasAcceptableInput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#acceptableInput-prop) every time [`textChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signal is emitted, and call [`edt2.setFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1) if it does.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a{argc, argv};

    QWidget w;
    QLineEdit lineEdit1;
    QLineEdit lineEdit2;
    //validator to accept two digits
    QRegExpValidator validator{QRegExp{"\\d{2}"}};
    lineEdit1.setValidator(&validator);
    lineEdit2.setValidator(&validator);
    QVBoxLayout layout{&w};
    layout.addWidget(&lineEdit1);
    layout.addWidget(&lineEdit2);
    w.show();

    QObject::connect(&lineEdit1, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](){
        if(lineEdit1.hasAcceptableInput())
            lineEdit2.setFocus();
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```